# CakePHP Tree Behavior, Multiple Trees Per Table

Tags: cakephp, tree, behavior, cakephp-1.2

I ran into a rather complex problem and I need the tree behavior to help.

I have a table called `nodes`, this table already has a tree and this tree is used to build a menu.

Now we want to make it possible to create multiple menus so I made the `node_menus` and `menus` tables. So `Nodes hasAndBelongsToMany Menus`

However there is a slight problem, the menus are built but uses `$this->Node->find('threaded')` so sub menus are possible. All nodes can be used in several menus and all menus need a tree so the nodes can be ordered and sub menus can be created as well.

For that I was thinking about creating one table containing trees for each menu and link a node to each row in the tree table.

So basically I need a `trees` table with a `Trees belongsTo Nodes` relation. In this tree i have the fields `menu_id`, `node_id`, `parent_id`, `lft` and `rght`.

Now the question is, are multiple trees possible in one table? Say, I want the tree where `menu_id` is 15. Would it be possible to use `find('threaded')` with said ID that would return all the data and the Nodes related to the `node_id`'s. Including all of the other core functions to create and manipulate the tree.

Is this possible? If not, does anyone have a better solution on how to make multiple menus where nodes can be places in multiple menus that can be ordered and threaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think like the following, then you can do it with a single tree.

```
root[hidden node]
---- Menu 1
-------- Item 1.1
-------- Item 1.2
-------- Item 1.3
---- Menu 2
-------- Sub Menu 2.1
------------ Item 2.1.1
-------- Item 2.1
---- Menu 3
---- Menu 4
---- Menu 5
```

I've made a menu builder plugins for CakePHP, you can use it if you like :)
https://github.com/torifat/cake-menu_builder

Comment: This might work! I have no idea why I always think more complicated then I have to. So I could do this in the menus table, relate the nodes to a menu item and retrieve the trees by looking for the children. And this would also make it much easier to manage. I'll give it a try!